# Dynamically resize height of datagridview

Tags: dynamic, datagridview, resize

Does anyone happen to know how to resize the height of a row in a datagridview as the user is editing inside of a cell?  I have the row resizing correctly by setting the wrapmode and autoresizemode, but this only takes affect after the enter key is hit.  I would like to resize the row as the user is entering text, so that they can see all of the text that they've entered.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.